# Taxonomy as checkboxes

Tags: metabox, taxonomy

So I'm trying to get Wordpress to display the categories as a series of select boxes in a custom meta box and am using some examples from this [tutorial](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/reusable-custom-meta-boxes-part-3-extra-fields/), but when I go to save the selection it generates additional categories in the form of the intended selections ID. It also fails to save more than one selection.

```
    <?php


    // Add the Meta Box
    function add_custom_meta_box() {
        add_meta_box(
            'custom_meta_box', // $id
            'Custom Meta Box', // $title 
            'show_custom_meta_box', // $callback
            'products', // $page
            'normal', // $context
            'high'); // $priority
    }
    add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_custom_meta_box');




      // Field Array
      $prefix = 'custom_';
      $custom_meta_fields = array(
        array(
            'label' => 'Category',
            'id'    => 'category',
            'type'  => 'tax_checkbox'
        ) );



      // The Callback
      function show_custom_meta_box() {
      global $custom_meta_fields, $post;
      // Use nonce for verification
      echo '<input type="hidden" name="custom_meta_box_nonce" value="'.wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)).'" />';

        // Begin the field table and loop
        echo '<table class="form-table">';
        foreach ($custom_meta_fields as $field) {
            // get value of this field if it exists for this post
            $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);
            // begin a table row with
            echo '<tr>
                    <th><label for="'.$field['id'].'">'.$field['label'].'</label></th>
                    <td>';
                    switch($field['type']) {



case 'tax_checkbox':


$terms = get_terms($field['id'],'get=all' );
$post_terms = wp_get_object_terms( get_the_ID(), $field['id'] );

$taxonomy = get_taxonomy( $field['id'] );

$checked = $post_terms ? $taxonomy->hierarchical ? $post_terms[0]->term_id : $post_terms[0]->slug : null;

foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                                $term_value = $taxonomy->hierarchical ? $term->term_id : $term->slug;
                                echo '<input type="checkbox" value="' . $term_value . '" name="' . $field['id'] . '[]" id="term-' . $term_value . '"' . checked( $checked, $term_value, false ) . ' /> <label for="term-' . $term_value . '">' . $term->name . '</label><br />';
                            }
                            echo '<span class="description">' . $field['desc'] . ' <a href="'.get_bloginfo( 'url' ) . '/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=' . $field['id'] . '&post_type=' . $page . '">Manage ' . $taxonomy->label . '</a></span>';
                        break;





                    } //end switch
            echo '</td></tr>';
        } // end foreach
        echo '</table>'; // end table
      }



    // Save the Data
    function save_custom_meta($post_id) {
        global $custom_meta_fields;

        // verify nonce
        if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['custom_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__))) 
            return $post_id;
        // check autosave
        if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
            return $post_id;
        // check permissions
        if ('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {
            if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id))
                return $post_id;
            } elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
                return $post_id;
        }

        // loop through fields and save the data
        foreach ($custom_meta_fields as $field) {


        if($field['type'] == 'tax_select') continue;  


        if( in_array( $field['type'], array( 'tax_checkboxes' ) ) ) {
                        // save taxonomies
                        if ( isset( $_POST[$field['id']] ) ) {
                            $term = $_POST[$field['id']];
                            wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $term, $field['id'] );
                        }
                    }

                    else {


            $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);
            $new = $_POST[$field['id']];
            if ($new && $new != $old) {
                update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);
            } elseif ('' == $new && $old) {
                delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);
            }
        } } // end foreach

        // save taxonomies
        $post = get_post($post_id);
        $category = $_POST['category'];
        wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $category, 'category' );
    }
    add_action('save_post', 'save_custom_meta');  



    ?>
```

Comment: if it helps, it's a hierarchical taxonomy I'm trying to work with.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure you cast all the terms as integers.  Passing in strings will compare the id's to the slugs, and end up creating new terms with the ids as the name.

#### Edit

Specifically, alter these two lines as follows (note the `intval`):

```
wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, intval( $term ), $field['id'] );
...
wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, intval( $category ), 'category' );
```

Comment: It should be passing the Term ID to the fields not the slugs, is it not?

Comment: @Picard102 I added examples to this answer for you. The answer is correct -- essentially, WordPress thought the IDs (e.g. "3") were strings. This works this way because you can have a category, tag, or other term that is in fact a number. Any data coming from a POST is a string by default, and you have to cast it to be anything different.